How to Perform a Full Name Search with Wildcards in GraphQL
I'm working with a GraphQL API and I'm trying to implement a search feature that allows users to search for patients by their first name, last name, or full name. I'm currently using a search condition with the ILIKE operator, but I'm having trouble getting it to work when searching for full names with a space in between, such as "Mary John".
Here's an example of the search condition I'm using:
{
  _text: {
    field: "patient.firstName",
    op: ILIKE,
    value: "doe%john"
  }
}

This condition is supposed to match a patient whose first name contains "Doe" followed by "John", but it's not returning the expected results.
I'm not sure if the GraphQL API I'm working with supports the ILIKE operator with wildcards in the way I'm expecting, or if there's a different approach I should take.
Here are my questions:

Does the GraphQL API typically support the use of the ILIKE operator with wildcards like % for pattern matching in string fields?
If so, what is the correct syntax to perform a search that includes a space, such as searching for a full name "Mary John"?
Are there any best practices or alternative approaches for implementing a full name search in GraphQL that can handle spaces and partial matches?


Short Answer
Unfortunately, the question you're asking is an impossible question to answer. The answer you're looking for is not to a GraphQL question, but to a backend implementation question that you haven't asked.
Long Answer
Think of GraphQL like you would think of JavaScript. It doesn't prescribe what queries should do, or how they should work. It describes you how to define a variable, how to define a function, or what the native types are. This is an equivalent question for JavaScript:

How do I pass variables into a JavaScript function to get it to search the database for users by first and last name?

The answer there, like the answer here, depends completely on what that function looks like, what that function does, and what database drivers that function is using. Whoever wrote that function could do almost literally anything.
Examples
This is a valid backend implementation for the GraphQL question you're asking, and the answer would be "there is nothing you can do with your query to get the result you want".
const searchHandler = (parent, args, context, info) => {
  return false;
}

This is also a valid backend implementation, and the answer would be "it depends on what the patient dataSource is doing. Is it using MongoDB, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, in-memory data? Is it parsing the arguments in a weird way, converting them from JSON into a string via string interpolation?
const searchHandler = (parent, args, context, info) => {
  const dataSource = context.dataSources.patient;

  return dataSource.search(args);
}


So the question you need to ask would include:

The GraphQL Schema
The Backend framework, implementation, and resolver code
The Database driver and data layer implementation code
If you're using some "out of the box solution", the name of it, and links to the documentation you're trying to use.

